# Kubernetes service externalIP

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with

1.1.1.1 master
2.2.2.2 worker
3.3.3.3 worker

In a service. I specify externalIP: 2.2.2.2

Should the pod selected by the service locate in 2.2.2.2 or it could locate in other workers?

My kubernetes is not hosted on aws or gce. No LoadBalancer supported.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have run on that specific node. The traffic will be forwarded by [kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-proxy/) to a pod selected by the service - regardless of where it's scheduled.

Comment: hi
I have an EC2 instance in which  I installed a single node cluster using microk8s, I have setup a proxy-controller (traefik) and assigned an externalIp to it’s service which is listening on http and https but unfortunately I can’t manage to access the service from outside the cluster, to check if it’s not a firewall issue I installed nginx and it works just fine on these ports, the error message is “ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED”

Answer (score 0):

For external services, you should use a load balancer and specify the load balancer's DNS name - not a minion IP.